# Add text, forms, etc. into reply body with Gmail Add-On

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I see methods in the [Gmail Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/) that allow you to compose drafts or send emails, but not what I need to do. I would like to have custom add-ons to insert various things into a reply I'm writing. These things can be as simple as text, or more complex like a form for receivers to response to.

For example, say you have several signatures depending on who you are responding to. The add-on has a button set of different signatures (i.e. personal, work, freelance, etc). I would like to be able to click in the box to reply, type a message, and click the add-on button to insert the desired signature at the end.

More complex example is to insert a mini customer satisfaction survey at the bottom of emails. You would type a message, then click insert on the add-on and it adds a mini form at the end of the email. The form is responded to by users without the add-on and has data stored in the Google Docs spreadsheet.

What method is used to insert text or forms into an in-progress reply message?

Comment: `GmailDraft#update`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can insert forms into a message body. Atleast for now.

However, plain text can be inserted. It is pretty simple. Just use the below method.

```js
function reply(body) {//pass a string 
var draft = GmailApp.createDraft(receiverEmail@gmail.com, "A sample subject",body );
var card = CardService.newComposeActionResponseBuilder().setGmailDraft(draft);
return card.build();
}
```